# how to change time column in HTML layout of Log4j2

Tags: logging, log4j2, layout

For my application I need HTML layout for logging events.The time in time column appears in milli seconds but I need it in dd-MM-yyyy:HH:mm:ss.sssZ format.
How do I do that?
Because HTML layout of log4j2 does not support pattern attribute. So I'm not able to set new pattern for time.

Answer (score 0):

Steps to change time column in HTML layout of Log4j2 :-

1) Create a class named CustomHTMLLayout with the code copied from HTMLLayout from lo4j2 source.

2) In method `public String toSerializable(final LogEvent event) {`, you can find below line of code

```
sbuf.append(event.getTimeMillis() - jvmStartTime);
```

You need to replace this with

```
sbuf.append(dateFormatter.format(new Date(event.getTimeMillis())));
```

where, dateFormatter is an instance of SimpleDateFormat.

3) In `log4j2.xml`, you need to do below changes -

```
<Configuration status="DEBUG" packages="com.helper">  
// You need to provide correct package name
```

`HtmlLayout` should be replaced by `CustomHTMLLayout`.

PS:- You can make it configurable by adding one more attribute in `@PluginFactory
    public static TransUnionHtmlLayout createLayout` and constructor.